# Current section title macro using titlesec

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec, etoolbox

I have a macro that contains the title for the current section, however when using the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), it no longer works for `\section` and `\subsection`. I know `titlesec` redefines the functions I'm using, but have not been able to figure out a workaround.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@sect}{\gdef\currtitle{#7}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@ssect}{\gdef\currtitle{#5}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@part}{\gdef\currtitle{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@spart}{\gdef\currtitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part*{First Starred part}
\currtitle

\part{First Un-starred part}
\currtitle

\section*{First Starred Section}
\currtitle

\section{Second Un-starred Section}
\currtitle

\subsection*{First Starred Subsection}
\currtitle

\subsection{Second Un-starred Subsection}
\currtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `\section` and lower level titles you can do

```
\apptocmd{\ttl@straight@i}{\global\let\currtitle\ttl@savetitle}{}{}
```

However, if you're not going to hide titles in groups, the simple

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currtitle}{\ttl@savetitle}
\makeatother
```

should suffice.

For `\part` your code still works and I believe also the similar one for `\chapter`.

In order to save only the current first level section title one can modify the code to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox,pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\ttl@straight@i}{\update@currsectitle{#1}}{}{}
\def\update@currsectitle#1{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{section}=0
    \global\let\currsectitle\ttl@savetitle
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Title of the first section}

\currsectitle

\subsection{A subsection}

\currsectitle

\section{Title of the second section}

\currsectitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first approach was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain how to use these commands? An example would really help.

Comment: How to get only section level and not the last sectioning command that occurred ? The problem with this command is that it may gives you the subsection or the paragraph title and not the section title. Maybe using `\ifnum` on `ttll@`.., but I did not succeeded with that yet.

Comment: @perror I added the code

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on egrep's answer, here is the code needed to get chapter title:

```latex
\pretocmd{\ttl@mkchap@i}{\def\ttl@savetitle{#7}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\ttl@mkchap@i}{\global\let\currchaptitle\ttl@savetitle}{}{}
```